# Data Crawling From Linkedin

Tags: cookies, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl data from Linkedin which use for a personal data crawling practice. But I can not crawl the data without login. So I used two way to simulate log in. One is to get the cookies from HttpClient, which will try to make a simulation login to get the cookies. the other is just add the cookie directly. But I failed both. I don't know the reason.
I used Framework Webmagic for the data crawling.
generally, adding Cookies directly will be an easy way. But I don't know whether I added the wrong cookies. 
Here's the thing. I wanna fetch data from the website https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/
And I added all the cookies at this page.

Here's all the cookies.

```
private Site site = Site.me().setRetryTimes(3).setSleepTime(100);
site.setCharset("utf-8")
   .setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36")
   .addHeader("accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8")
   .addHeader("accept-encoding","gzip, deflate, br")
   .addHeader("accept-language:en-US","en;q=0.8")
   .addHeader("connection", "keep-alive")
   .addHeader("referer","https://www.linkedin.com/")
   .addCookie(".linkedin.com","lidc", "b=TB91:g=750:u=38:i=1503815541:t=1503895683:s=AQE5xZLW6mVmRdHBY9qNO-YOiyAnKtgk")
   .addCookie(".linkedin.com","lang", "v=2&lang=en-us")
   .addCookie(".linkedin.com","_lipt", "CwEAAAFeIo5-jXjgrpSKF4JfxzNbjC6328JPUgtSHQIKtSDyk4Bockuw84uMkCwbKS0TzUOM_w8Al4s9YjFFF-0T43TPtfG_wv-JNVXsPeO8mVxaYwEcTGiyOdyaRZOCIK7qi02EvZUCtjsaTpAos60U4XrFnu1FO-cY1LrzpqDNUmfrqWJPjSoZpOmjeKtTh-nHcdgpruvjf237E78dqMydLLd1A0Uu7Kr7CmNIurXFd9-Z4hwevLRd3SQMEbSRxAwCclgC4tTzEZ5KoFmpI4veKBFGOqF5MCx3hO9iNRdHrJC44hfRx-Bw7p__PYNWF8sc6yYd0deF-C5aJpronFUYp3vXiwt023qm6T9eRqVvtH1BRfLwCZOJmYrGbKzq4plzNKM7DnHKHNV_cjJQtc9aD3JQz8n2GI-cHx2PYubUyIjVWWvntKWC-EUtn4REgL4jmIaWzDUVz3nkEBW7I3Wf6u2TkuAVu9vq_0mW_dTVDCzgASk")
   .addCookie(".linkedin.com","_ga", "GA1.2.2091383287.1503630105")
   .addCookie(".www.linkedin.com","li_at", "AQEDAReIjksE2n3-AAABXiKOYVQAAAFeRprlVFYAV8gUt-kMEnL2ktiHZG-AOblSny98srz2r2i18IGs9PqmSRstFVL2ZLdYOcHfPyKnBYLQPJeq5SApwmbQiNtsxO938zQrrcjJZxpOFXa4wCMAuIsN")
   .addCookie(".www.linkedin.com","JSESSIONID", "ajax:4085733349730512988")
   .addCookie(".linkedin.com","liap", "true")
   .addCookie(".www.linkedin.com","sl","v=1&f68pf")
   .addCookie("www.linkedin.com","visit", "v=1&M")
   .addCookie(".www.linkedin.com","bscookie", "v=1&201708250301246c8eaadc-a08f-4e13-8f24-569529ab1ce0AQEk9zZ-nB0gizfSrOSucwXV2Wfc3TBY")
   .addCookie(".linkedin.com","bcookie", "v=2&d2115cf0-88a6-415a-8a0b-27e56fef9e39");
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn is very difficult to crawl, not just technically but they also [sue people who do](https://techcrunch.com/2016/08/15/linkedin-sues-scrapers/).

When they detect an IP as a possible bot, they give you the login page. Most IP addresses known for bots by them are now serving a login page. New ranges do not last very long.

They're probably just pretty confident you're a bot and keeping you from logging in.